# "Converting" a System.out.print to return

Tags: java, return

I have the following problem.
I have a method that draws something like this:

```
public static String Method(){
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
System.out.print("*")
}
for(int y=0; y<40; y++){
System.out.println();
}
return ?????;
```

I need this method to actually return the stuff that it draws as a String - but how? I thought about creating a new String and just += add all the lines, but how can I implement a line jump? And ist this the way to go?

Comment: What do you mean by a _line jump_? A `\n`?

Comment: Line separator is also a String. Check [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--).

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the first print statement fyi.

Comment: I would also not use `+=` when building a `String` since you create a new `String` object every time. Use instead `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks, i'll read into Stringbuilder. And I'd like to add that my question is not a duplicate, as the main question is how to turn a System.out.print into a return statement. (And there's pretty much nothing on the internet about it)

Answer (score -3):

Implement a line jump (called a "newline") with `"\n"`.

Comment: `System.lineSeparator()` is OS independant

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you could post that as an answer instead of comment it everywhere.

Comment: I love to comment more than posting answers :)